# Analyzing data from same tables in different db instances

Tags: sql, oracle, missing-data, merging-data

### Short version:

How can I map two columns from table A and B if they both have a common identifier which in turn may have two values in column C

Lets say:

```
A
---
 1 , 2 

B
--- 
 ? , 3 


C 
----- 
45, 2
45, 3
```

Using table C I know that id 2 and 3 belong to the same item ( 45 ) and thus "?" in table B should be 1.

What query could do something like that?

**EDIT**

Long version omitted. It was really boring/confusing

**EDIT**

I'm posting some output here.

From this query:

```
select distinct( rolein) , activityin from taskperformance@dm_prod where activityin in ( 
    select activityin from activities@dm_prod where activityid in ( 
        select activityid from activities@dm_prod where activityin in ( 
            select distinct( activityin ) from taskperformance where rolein = 0 
        )
    )
)
```

I have the following parts:

```
select distinct( activityin ) from taskperformance where rolein = 0
```

Output:

http://question1337216.pastebin.com/f5039557

```
    select activityin from activities@dm_prod where activityid in ( 
        select activityid from activities@dm_prod where activityin in ( 
            select distinct( activityin ) from taskperformance where rolein = 0 
        )
    )
```

Output:

http://question1337216.pastebin.com/f6cef9393

And finally:

```
select distinct( rolein) , activityin from taskperformance@dm_prod where activityin in ( 
    select activityin from activities@dm_prod where activityid in ( 
        select activityid from activities@dm_prod where activityin in ( 
            select distinct( activityin ) from taskperformance where rolein = 0 
        )
    )
)
```

Output:

http://question1337216.pastebin.com/f346057bd

Take for instance activityin  335 from first query ( from taskperformance B) .

It is present in activities from A.

But is not in taskperformance in A ( but a the related activities: 92, 208, 335, 595 )

Are present in the result. The corresponding role in is: 1

Comment: Do you need to run this update just one time, or repeatedly throughout the life of the project?

Comment: No, just one time ever. For some previous problems I have even print the output to a file and then search and replace stuff. Like select columnA from table and then copy/past in a file and search and replace  s/number/insert into table $1 where value = $2 etc...

Comment: But at this point my head hurts so much I cannot think on "creative" alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got it.

It seems that I just didn't develop the section of the brain that helps to make queries.

Here's the result

```
select distinct(  a.rolein ) , a.activityin, b.activityin 
from 
    taskperformance@dm_prod a,
    taskperformance b, 
    activities@dm_prod c,
    activities d
where b.rolein = 0
    and b.activityin = d.activityin 
    and d.activityid = c.activityid
    and c.activityin = a.activityin
order by b.activityin , a.activityin
```

Thank you JYelton, your questions helped me to understand my own question better.

Comment: Glad I was able to help, I am not sure my final suggestion would give in the same results as what you came up with, but it was a good mind bender. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like for any given `activityin`, the same `rolein` value applies. Thus if database A (db1) has at least one association for each for the rolein/activityin relationships, you can populate database B (db2) with a simple one-time update query:

```
UPDATE db2.taskperformance
SET db2.taskperformance.rolein =
(SELECT db1.taskperformance.rolein
FROM db1.taskperformance
WHERE db1.taskperformance.activityin = db2.taskperformance.activityin);
```

I strongly advise backing up the database first before running the query as it will change all the `rolein` values, and if my assumption is incorrect, you may have bad data.

**EDIT**

Although I think it could be done in one query, it's beyond my knowledge of sql. However I think the following will work: Create a temporary table that contains all the `rolein` values for each `activityin` value in database A. This table essentially becomes an activities table, except now you have numbers replacing the `activityid` values, which can be looked up to fill in the missing values of `rolein` for database B.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE db2.ttable
SELECT db1.taskperformance.rolein, db1.activities.activityin
FROM db1.taskperformance, db1.activities
WHERE db1.taskperformance.activityin = db1.activities.activityin;
```

From the original data, this yields:

```
rolein     activityin 
1          1          
1          2          
2          3          
2          4          
3          6          
3          7          
3          7
```

Now you should be able to run the update query against this temporary table:

```
UPDATE db2.taskperformance
SET db2.taskperformance.rolein =
(SELECT db2.ttable.rolein
FROM db2.ttable
WHERE db2.taskperformance.activityin = db2.ttable.activityin);
```

The problem with this will be if you have unique values in database B for `activityin` that do not occur in database A.

Finally:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE db2.ttable;
```

For completeness' sake.

Comment: Indeed, actually I've got it updated like that for all the records whose activityin matched in both tables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331294/update-column-with-values-from-another-column . The problem now is when they do not match directly in taskperformace ( they don't have same activtiyin ) but they do match in the activities.  ( like 1,1 in db1 and ?,2 in db2 and activties have ( {"start",1 } {"start",2} )  :( :( :(

Comment: Which activities table would have the correct associations for the data in database B? Or to elaborate: is the activities table identical in both databases?

Comment: no, that's the problem. They do have identical "labels" but different id ( for 75% of the cases... ) no.. about 90% they are identical. The missing 10% is the one that cause me in first place to have the rolein empty in the first migration attempt. :(

Comment: BTW +1 for the support :P  ( let me warn you'll become addicted )

Comment: Thank you. It is a semi-complicated issue but I think it can be readily solved. So my next (and hopefully final) question is: Can the activities table in database A can be used to populate all of the rolein values of taskperformance in database B (ignoring the activities table of database B)?

Comment: Yes they can. The problem I guess will be... how can I know what values belong to which activity in B. But yes, all the activities from A could be "contain" all the posible roles of taskperformance in B ( that is, both have the same amount of role/actitivies )